# Racetrack game with reading the track from a file

Tags: haskell, serialization, community-challenge

For this community challenge I made the racetrack game. I'm reading the race data from a text file, [which is available here](https://github.com/bruno-cadorette/Racetrack/raw/master/game1.txt). This is only playable by entering the velocity at the console.

I've got two modules. I'm open for any comments.

**Racetrack.hs**

```
import Data.Serialize
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BStr
import Text.Read(readMaybe)
import RacetrackGameData  

zipT :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, a) -> (b, b) -> (c, c)
zipT f (x,y) (x', y') = (f x x',f y y')


isCrossingTheLine :: (Point,Point)->Point->Point->Bool            
isCrossingTheLine line origin target = 
    let 
        reduce = uncurry $ zipT (-)
        (dx,dy) = reduce line
        (dx',dy') = reduce (origin, target)
    in 0 /= dx * dy' - dx' * dy 

updatePlayer :: Player -> Point -> Player    
updatePlayer player newVelocity = player { position = newPosition, velocity = newVelocity }
    where newPosition = zipT (+) (position player) newVelocity



playerInput :: Player -> IO Player
playerInput player = do
    velo' <- safeGetLine $ "You must type a tuple like this one " ++ (show $ velocity player)
    if uncurry (&&) $ zipT verify (velocity player) velo' then
        return $ updatePlayer player velo' 
    else do
        putStrLn "You must specify a valid new velocity"
        playerInput player
    where
        verify x x' = (x' - x) `elem` [-1, 0, 1]



playGame :: [Player] -> Game -> IO ()  
playGame allPlayers game = play allPlayers
    where
        play [] = error "No players"
        play players@(current:nexts) = do
            print current
            putStrLn $ prettyGameOutput players game
            current' <- playerInput current
            if playerIsInValidState current' $ gameBoard game then
                if isCrossingTheLine (finishLine game) (position current) (position current') then
                    putStrLn $ "Player " ++ show (playerId current) ++ " won the game!"
                else
                    play (nexts ++ [current'])
            else
                putStrLn "Game over"



safeGetLine :: (Read a) => String ->  IO a
safeGetLine errorMessage = do 
    pt <- fmap readMaybe getLine
    case pt of
        Just p -> return p
        Nothing -> do
            putStrLn errorMessage
            safeGetLine errorMessage


main :: IO()
main = do
    decodedGame <- fmap decode $ BStr.readFile "game1.txt"
    putStrLn "How many player wants to play?"
    n <- safeGetLine "You must specify a number"
    case decodedGame of
        Left err -> putStrLn err
        Right game -> playGame (map (\i -> Player (startPosition game) (0,0) i) [0..n]) game
```

**RacetrackGameData.hs**

```
module RacetrackGameData (serializeGame, Game(..), Point, Cell(..), Player(..), playerIsInValidState, prettyGameOutput) where
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Matrix
import Data.Serialize
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BStr
type Point = (Int, Int)
data Player = Player { position :: Point, velocity :: Point, playerId :: Int } deriving (Show)
data Cell = Empty | Wall deriving (Show, Eq)
data Game = Game { gameBoard :: Matrix Cell, startPosition :: Point, finishLine :: (Point, Point) } deriving (Show)
instance Serialize Game where
    put = put . serializeGame
    get = fmap deserializeGame get

serializeGame :: Game -> BStr.ByteString
serializeGame (Game board start finish) = BStr.unlines $ (BStr.pack $ show start) : (BStr.pack $ show finish) : serializeBoard
    where
        serializeBoard = 
             map (BStr.pack . map serializeCell) $ toLists $ board
        serializeCell Empty = '0'
        serializeCell Wall = '1'

readBStr :: (Read a) => BStr.ByteString -> a        
readBStr = read . BStr.unpack
deserializeGame :: BStr.ByteString -> Game
deserializeGame str = Game getBoard (readBStr startPos) (readBStr line) 
    where
        (startPos:line:board) = BStr.lines $ BStr.filter (\x -> x /= '\r') str
        getBoard =  fromLists $ map (map deserializeCell . BStr.unpack) $ board
        deserializeCell '0' = Empty
        deserializeCell '1' = Wall
        deserializeCell e = error $ "The character "++ show e ++ " is invalid"

playerIsInValidState :: Player -> Matrix Cell -> Bool    
playerIsInValidState player board = 
    let (x, y) = position player
    in getElem x y board == Empty        

prettyGameOutput :: [Player] -> Game -> String
prettyGameOutput players (Game board _ line)  = 
    unlines $ toLists $ matrix (nrows board) (ncols board) (\(i,j)->printCell (getElem i j board) (i, j))
        where
        printCell cell pos = 
            getFirstOrDefault ' ' 
                [(const 'F') <$> (elemIsFinishPoint pos),
                (const '+') <$> (whenMaybe (Wall ==) cell),
                (head . show . playerId) <$> (find (\p -> pos == position p) players)]

        getFirstOrDefault defValue = fromJust . fromMaybe (Just defValue) . find isJust
        whenMaybe p x = if p x then Just x else Nothing
        elemIsFinishPoint = whenMaybe (\x-> (\(a,b)-> a==x||b==x) $ line)
```

Comment: How do I run this? I tried `runhaskell Racetrack.hs`, but then `Data.Serialize` was missing, so I installed the `cereal` package. Then `Data.Matrix` was missing, so I installed the `matrix` package. Now I get `Not in scope: '<$>'`.

Comment: Perhaps you're using an old version of GHC. In 7.10, <$> is in the prelude, so just import Data.Functor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### --- playGame

Your `playGame` function has this structure:

```
playGame players@(current:rest) = do
    ...
    playGame (rest ++ current')
```

Note that the list concatenation `as ++ bs` is O(*n*) where *n* is the size of `as`. That is, `as` basically gets copied, so this method of rotating a list is not efficient.

In practice this probably won't matter since the `players` list will be small, but it is something to keep in mind. A data structure which amortizes the copying might work better in this case is a *difference list* such as is implemented by the [dlist](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist) package.

Alternatively just use a `Data.Map` where the key is a player number, and keep track of whose turn it is with an Int modulo the number of players - much like you would do in a conventional language.

#### --- playerIsInValidState

You should have a bounds check here. If (x,y) is out of bounds then `getElem` will throw an exception.

#### --- general organization

Games typically have the following types and organization:

```
GameState  - a data type recording the state of the game
Move       - a type representing a possible move

step :: GameState -> Move -> GameState
  -- apply the move to the game state returning the 
  -- new game state
```

If a move can produce simple output, perhaps use this form for `step`:

```
step :: GameState -> Move -> (GameState, String)
```

Note that `step` is a *pure* function which makes it very easy to test. You can create unit tests for your code which may be run automatically by your build process. Pure functions are also a lot easier to test directly in a ghci session.

Your game loop can now look like this:

```
gameLoop :: GameState -> IO ()
gameLoop state = do
  move <- askPlayer state
  let (state', output) = step state move
  if (not $ null output)
    then putStrLn output
    else return ()
  if gameOver state
    then return ()
    else gameLoop state'
```

where `askPlayer` and `gameOver` have the following signatures:

```
askPlayer :: GameState -> IO Move
  -- ask the current player for a move

gameOver :: GameState -> Bool
  -- return True if the game is over
```

Comment: Nice! thanks a lot :)

However, there is an easier way to write your conditions in the gameLoop function

...
when (not $ null output) (putStrLn output)
unless (gameOver state) (gameLoop state')

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this counts as a code review, but these are my observations when running the program:

#### 1. User interface

After starting the game and answering how many players want to play, I am presented with a view of the racetrack. Somewhere on the track is a `0` which I guess is my current position.

I don't know what I am supposed to do now and press Enter.
The game asks me to "type a tuple". But what should the meaning of that tuple be? I enter `(10, 15)` and the game now replies that I must "specify a new valid velocity". But what is a valid new velocity? What is my current velocity? Since this is my first move I guess that my velocity is currently `(0, 0)` and I enter `(1, 0)`, which brings me to...

#### 2. Bugs

After entering `(1, 0)` the game tells me that I have won. That's great ... But I barely made my first move, let alone completed a lap! This can't be  right.